# How to *not* render rmarkdown (.Rmd) files on Shiny Server

Tags: r, r-markdown, shiny-server

I have a rather stupid simple question but my Google searching has come up empty: I have some Rmarkdown files on a shiny server which I've compiled into `.html`. How do I tell shiny server to **not** render the `.Rmd` files into `.html`?

So, if I have something like this in my directory, I want shiny server to use the `.html` file directly.

```
index.html # use this
index.Rmd  # Oh, index.html already exists. Don't recompile index.Rmd
```

For now, I've gone ahead and just placed the `.Rmd` files in a subdirectory so the server only sees the `.html` files when it's in the main directory but I'm wondering if there's a simpler way.

Comment: Yes, I think the best way to handle this is to use (continuous) deployment which only makes the HTML files available to Shiny Server, and leave the RMD source files in the source repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, yeah. We pick up any `/\.rmd$/i` file as the file you *really* wanted to show your users. You'd have to give it another extension (`index.rmd.notreally` or `index.rmark`) to get around that. Or put it in a subdirectory as you've already discovered.

Sorry about that. I'll jot that down as a feature request.

Comment: No problem. I think it may be preferable actually to force the user to use one of your options suggested. Otherwise, I can imagine the situation where someone does something like `render(input...)` to generate the .html files, then edits the `.Rmd` file and reloads the page to see the updated `.html` only to have the old version up there, potentially leading to confusion. I guess you could compare timestamps but that too seems like a lot of work for not much gain.

Comment: Maybe you could add this behavior to the documentation though. :)